# How to prevent an illegal memory access or catch the segfault within C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, gdb, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VSC extension for C++. When reaching a breakpoint the extension is calling a function within the C++ process for each variable from the actual scope. The variables names and types I can get with the Debug Adapter Protocol variable request. But since I only get a list with all variables of the actual scope I am not able to differ between intialized and non intialized pointers. As well as I don't know if the memory it is pointing to is initialized or maybe already have been freed.

Especially when trying to access memory where a non-intialized pointer refers to I get a segmentation fault.

I was considering to use "access_ok" to check the pointers validity in advance or alternatively to try to catch the segfaults while accessing the pointer so that the program doesn't crash because of this extension. But since I am not writing a kernel application I am not able to include such functionality. Is there a way to prevent such illegal access in advance? Preferably a cross-system one (Windows, MacOS and Linux)?

Comment: There is no need to write a kernel application to catch Access Violation exceptions. On Windows this could be done with [SEH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-170). However a better idea is to query memory mapping (similar to [vmmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap)) and figure out whether target memory range is valid and accessible or not prior to actually accessing it. Obviously there is no cross-platform solution here.

Comment: Note that having a debugger _automatically_ (i.e. without explicit user request) calling into the application is a _terrible_ idea. You have no idea what state the application is, it may already be corrupt. Calling into the application will corrupt the state _more_, making it so much harder to debug.